# Как передать var в другой класс

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Переменную var нельзя сделать публичной, а это значит ее нельзя вызвать в другом классе.
У меня 2 класса, в одном есть переменная var, а в другом нужно к ней обратиться, как поступить?

```
private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dg2.ItemsSource = me.ToList();
        }





class ExcelImportSheet
    {

        internal class Metric
        {
            public int IDОбращения { get; set; }
            public string IdКлиента { get; set; }
            public string ФИО { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Услуга { get; set; }
            public string Статус { get; set; }
            public string ОценкаКлиента { get; set; }


        }
        public IEnumerable<Metric> EnumerateMetrics(string xlsxpath)
        {


            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {

                var excelFilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }

            using (var excelFilePath = new XLWorkbook(xlsxpath))

            using (var worksheet = excelFilePath.Worksheets.Worksheet(1))
            {

                for (int row = 2; row <= 10; ++row)
                {
                    var me = new Metric
                   
                    {
                        IDОбращения = excelFilePath.Cell("A5:A100").GetValue<int>(),
                        IdКлиента = excelFilePath.Cell("B5:B100").GetValue<string>(),
                        ФИО = excelFilePath.Cell("C5:C100").GetValue<string>(),
                        Email = excelFilePath.Cell("D5:D100").GetValue<string>(),
                        Услуга = excelFilePath.Cell("E5:E100").GetValue<string>(),
                        Статус = excelFilePath.Cell("F5:F100").GetValue<string>(),
                        ОценкаКлиента = excelFilePath.Cell("G5:G100").GetValue<string>(),

                    };
                    yield return me;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var` - это значит "Автоматический тип", то есть это удобство для вас, разработчика, чтоб не пришлось постоянно писать тип нужных вам данных. Условно вы написали `var value = "Привет мир!";`, вы знаете, что в скобках у вас строка, и вот чтоб не писать `string value = "Привет мир!";` вам позволяют этот тип опустить, за вас автоматически подставят нужное после компиляции проекта. Если вы только начинаете путь в программировании, то забудьте про var, он вас только запутает. Исходя из этого всего, у вас переменная имеет нужный тип, наведите мышь и увидите его. Вот этот тип и передавайте в класс.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Покажите код, потому что указанное описание можно трактовать по-разному. Как именно возникла такая потребность?

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу. Пытаюсь сделать импорт данных из Excel в DataGrid

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Локальная переменная на то и локальная, что к ней никак нельзя получить доступ извне.

Проиллюстрирую вопрос, к примеру есть 2 класса, в одном из них метод с локальной переменной:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        int x = 42;
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x); // ОШИБКА! где взять "x"?
    }
}
```

Допустим вы хотите запустить этот код так:

```
var obj1 = new MyClass();
obj1.MyMethod();
var obj2 = new AnotherClass();
obj2.MyMethod();
```

Проиллюстрирую несколько способов решения.

#### Возвращаемое значение и передача аргумента

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyMethod()
    {
        int x = 42;
        return x;
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    public void MyMethod(int x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x);
    }
}
```

```
var obj1 = new MyClass();
int x = obj1.MyMethod();
var obj2 = new AnotherClass();
obj2.MyMethod(x);
```

Здесь передача простая, через вызывающий код.

#### Публичное поле и передача в конструктор

```
class MyClass
{
    public int x;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        x = 42;
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    private MyClass _mc;

    public AnotherClass(MyClass mc)
    {
        _mc = mc;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_mc.x);
    }
}
```

```
var obj1 = new MyClass();
obj1.MyMethod();
var obj2 = new AnotherClass(obj1);
obj2.MyMethod();
```

Здесь экземпляр класса `AnotherClass` полностью получает доступ ко всем публичным членам экземпляра `MyClass` - не только полям, но и методам. Еще говорят, "`AnotherClass` имеет зависимость от `MyClass`".

#### Статическое публичное поле (НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ)

```
class MyClass
{
    public static int x;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        x = 42;
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(MyClass.x);
    }
}
```

```
var obj1 = new MyClass();
obj1.MyMethod();
var obj2 = new AnotherClass();
obj2.MyMethod();
```

Несмотря на простоту, это наихудший вариант решения задачи, но я был должен показать, что он есть. Главная его проблема, что данный подход несовместим с ООП. То есть если у вас будет более одного экземпляра `MyClass`, то что-нибудь сломается, потому что статические члены класса - общие для всех экземпляров. Статику нужно использовать с умом и только тогда, когда она нужна осознанно, и без неё никак.

---

Ваш случай решается простым созданием экземпляра второго класса прямо в нужном методе.

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var obj = new ExcelImportSheet();
        dg.ItemsSource = obj.EnumerateMetrics();
    }
}

class ExcelImportSheet
{
    public IEnumerable<Metric> EnumerateMetrics()
    {
        // ...
        yield return me;
    }
}
```

Либо так, чтобы не создавать новый объект на каждый вызов метода.

```
class MyClass
{
    private ExcelImportSheet _obj = new ExcelImportSheet();

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        dg.ItemsSource = _obj.EnumerateMetrics();
    }
}

class ExcelImportSheet
{
    public IEnumerable<Metric> EnumerateMetrics()
    {
        // ...
        yield return me;
    }
}
```

`.ToList()` вызывать не нужно, это лишнее, `DataGrid` поддерживает `IEnumerable<T>`.

---

Окей, вот полный пример, как бы я написал, исправив все ошибки

```
private ExcelImportSheet _eis = new ExcelImportSheet();

private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        string path = openFileDialog.FileName;
        dg2.ItemsSource = _eis.EnumerateMetrics(path);
    }
}
```

```
internal class Metric
{
    public int IDОбращения { get; set; }
    public string IdКлиента { get; set; }
    public string ФИО { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Услуга { get; set; }
    public string Статус { get; set; }
    public string ОценкаКлиента { get; set; }
}

class ExcelImportSheet
{
    public IEnumerable<Metric> EnumerateMetrics(string xlsxpath)
    {           
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(xlsxpath))
        using (var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1))
        {
            for (int row = 3; row <= 5; ++row)
            {
                var me = new Metric
                {
                    IDОбращения = worksheet.Cell($"A{row}").GetValue<int>(),
                    IdКлиента = worksheet.Cell($"B{row}").GetValue<string>(),
                    ФИО = worksheet.Cell($"C{row}").GetValue<string>(),
                    Email = worksheet.Cell($"D{row}").GetValue<string>(),
                    Услуга = worksheet.Cell($"E{row}").GetValue<string>(),
                    Статус = worksheet.Cell($"F{row}").GetValue<string>(),
                    ОценкаКлиента = worksheet.Cell($"G{row}").GetValue<string>(),
                };
                yield return me;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145164/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot---var---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.